# Как получить доступ к Edit1, если ругается "undeclared identifier Edit1"

Tags: delphi, vcl

Есть функция. Во время своей работы функция должна запросить данные у пользователя через компонент TEdit и сохранить в виде целочисленных переменных. Выглядит это пока так.

```
function translate(): boolean;
var tx, ty: integer;
begin
  tx := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  ty := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
end;
```

При этом компилятор говорит:

> undeclared identifier Edit1

При том что Edit1 и Edit2 инициализированны в самом начале. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: "Edit1 и Edit2 инициализированны в самом начале" - в самом начале чего?

Comment: В начале программы.В разделе type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы иметь доступ к компонентам формы, функция должна быть членом класса формы:

```
function Form1.translate():boolean;
```

или получать ссылки на компоненты в виде параметров:

```
function translate(Edit1, Edit2: TEdit): boolean;
```

Comment: ... или просто дописывать вначале название формы к которой они принадлежат: `tx := StrToInt(Form1.Edit1.Text);`

Comment: @Isaev  - самый плохой вариант - завязка на глобальную переменную формы. Их декларации вообще надо удалять из юнитов.

Comment: ну так и Edit1, Edit2 не лучшие имена. Когда проект подразумевает 1 форму и макс 50 строк и это единственная проблема, то вполне себе вариант. Для новичков (а это тот случай, раз эта ошибка вызывает вопросы) этот вариант максимально понятен и прост